# How to nest layouts in twig

Tags: php, twig

Let's say I have a main layout, and then some inner pages that require their own layout, because they have a sub-navigation.

I thought something like this would work:

```
{#layout.twig#}
{% block content %} {% endblock %}

{#sublayout.twig#}
{% extends "layout.twig" %}
{% block content %} 
   <div id="subnav">{% global_variable %}</div>
   {% block sub_content %} 
   {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}

{#innerpage.twig#}
{% extends "sublayout.twig" %}
{% block content %} 
   {% block sub_content %} 
   {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

This gives me a error like `Unexpected tag name "global_variable" (expecting closing tag for the "block" tag`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess its a variable, so it should be like so:

```
{{ global_variable }}
```